# MIPS homework, factorial for large number

Tags: mips, factorial

I have to write program that calculates factorial for large numbers (e.g 200). This is very important for me. Here is my code:

```
  .text
    main:
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li $v0, 5
    syscall
    move $s0, $v0
    move $t1, $v0
    li $t0, 1
    loop:
    mul $t0, $t0, $s0

    addi $s0, $s0, -1
    bgtz $s0, loop

    li $v0, 1
    move $a0, $t0
    syscall

    li $v0, 10
    syscall

    .data
    prompt: .asciiz "\nGive a number: "
```

This program works only for numbers less than 31. I don't know how to fix it. Someone can help me?

P.S Sorry for my bad language.

Comment: Where is the petla label in your code?

Comment: Also the limit for signed integers is 2,147,483,647 or 2^31 - 1. You are actually encountering an integer overflow. Try using 24 as input it should output negative as well.

Comment: I know, why the result for big number is bad, but i don't know how fix  it. Can you explain me your last sentence?

Comment: Any value `n >= 13` has a factorial value larger than what can be shown in a 32-bit integer.

Answer (score 1):

The point of this homework assignment is for the student to implement arbitrary precision integer addition and multiplication in MIPS, and then use it to implement the factorial algorithm. [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Example) is an example for arbitrary precision factorial in pseudo-code.